# C# Having trouble with a array

Tags: c#

Keep In mind I don't have much coding experience...

I'm having problem's accessing an Array. 
I'm creating the Array using a function that returns a Array here's an example:

```
int[] ArrayName = ReturnArray(string);
```

So now that ArrayName has been created it should be identical to what ReturnArray returned should it not?

Well I set a breakpoint right on :

```
int[] ArrayName = ReturnArray(string);
```

I can see that ArrayName was created properly.

Well when I try to access just 1 value of the Array like so:

```
print(ArrayName[0]);
```

It should only return the first value in the array right? well It's not!
It returns a MORE THAN ONE VALUE and the value's Don't even match what ReturnArray(string) Returned

Here is the "ReturnArray" function :

```
    public static int[] ReturnArray(string t)
    {
        int i,ii,;
        string ba;
        string base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (i = 0; i < t.Length;i++)
        {
            ba = t.Substring(i, 1);
            ii = base64.IndexOf(ba) * 64;
            list.Add(ii);
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Added more code do to response's from comments

```
    private void outputLoop()
    {
        int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 63; i++)
            {
                int te = lines[i].Length - 128;
                string tes = lines[i].Substring(te, 64);
                int[] ArrayName = ReturnArray(tes);
                _textlayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[i].ToString(), new Vector2(1100, i * 15), Color.White);
          }
    }
```

Comment: What your `print` function do? It is insanely hard to guess on behavior of code the only you can see. Consider making self contained sample (similar to what Tim Medora have in his (+1) answer). Make console project and use Console.WriteLine, add comments on what you gat and what you wxpect (instead all caps "MORE THAN ONE VALUE").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working sample. Let's deconstruct.

```
static void Main( string[] args ) {
    // declare a variable and assign it to the return value of ReturnArray()
    var arr = ReturnArray( "foo" ); 

    // get the first value in the array
    var first = arr[0];
}

public static int[] ReturnArray( string t ) {
    int i, ii;
    string ba;
    string base64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for( i = 0; i < t.Length; i++ ) {
        ba = t.Substring( i, 1 );
        ii = base64.IndexOf( ba ) * 64;
        list.Add( ii );
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

First, if you are trying to make a base 64 algorithm, it's already been done and [in the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx). If you are trying to learn, that's great, but there are examples out there to go on.

```
ii = base64.IndexOf( ba ) * 64;
```

Secondly, your code does return what I would expect, i.e. an array of numbers which come from the product of `IndexOf() * 64`.

This little example yields `1984, 2560, 2560` for "foo" and the value at index 0 is 1984.

"AAA" yields `0, 0, 0`, because IndexOf() is 0 * 64.

As you would expect, "BBB" yields `64, 64, 64`, because IndexOf() returns 1, and it is multiplied by 64.

More debugging code (based on comments):

```
int[] arr = ReturnArray( "DADBALAMANAOAAABAYAZAaAbAcAdAeAff/BIBJBKBLBMBNBOBJBKBLBMBNBOBPf/AAABAoApAqArAsAt‌​AuAvf/f/+4+5f/f/f/AAABf/B4B5B6DQAZAaAbAcAdAeAZAa" );

// should print "192"
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( arr[0] );
```

Comment: In theory you're correct but for some reason It seems to not be functioning correctly for me..

Comment: What *do* you get, i.e. what input yields what result, and how are you outputting that result?

Comment: DADBALAMANAOAAABAYAZAaAbAcAdAeAff/BIBJBKBLBMBNBOBJBKBLBMBNBOBPf/AAABAoApAqArAsAtAuAvf/f/+4+5f/f/f/AAABf/B4B5B6DQAZAaAbAcAdAeAZAa

would be 192,0 ,192 ,64 ,0 ,704 and so on correct? and indeed what it returns is correct...I'm outputting Array[0] with XNA

like:

_textlayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[0].ToString(), new Vector2(1100, x * 15), Color.White);

Comment: Those values look correct...what if you use Debug.WriteLine(arr[0])...do you get 192?

Comment: and it outputs more than just 1 value what is weird though is if i do something like 

                    _tilelayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[0].ToString(), new Vector2(1100, x * 15), Color.White);
                    _tilelayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[1].ToString(), new Vector2(1160, x * 15), Color.White);
                    _tilelayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[2].ToString(), new Vector2(1220, x * 15), Color.White);
                    _tilelayer.DrawString(_font, ArrayName[3].ToString(), new Vector2(1280, x * 15), Color.White);

and take the first value that is outputted

Comment: from each line it seems to be correct but that doesn't make sense

Comment: Maybe you should post more of your code...it seems like the array function is doing what you want it to, but it's being called/consumed incorrectly.

Comment: Debug.WriteLine(arr[0]) for me would output 192,0,0,0,64,64,0,0,0,0,64,64,64,64,128,128 ectttt

when it should only output 192 ....

Comment: okay, just so we are both looking at exactly the same thing, I posted the debug code I am using.

Comment: So it's screwing up for you also?

Comment: No, the code I posted prints a single value from the array. It is working as I would expect.

Comment: I added how I'm outputting it to give you an example

Comment: Okay, so I would expect that code to loop 63 times, and each time ouput one value from the array, since you have `ArrayName[i].ToString()`.

Comment: Ok so if in that loop I change ArrayName[i] to ArrayName[0] it should only return 1 value correct? and It should output that 1 same value 63 times?

Comment: It will return the same (first) value over and over as the loop runs.

Comment: well it doesn't return's 192 then 0 then 0 then 0 then 64 then 64 then 0 then 0 then 0  then 0  then 64 then 64 then 64 then 64 ect.....

when it should only be repeating 192 over and over correct?

Comment: Since you are getting the array with every iteration of the loop, the value will depend on whatever your `tes` variable is: `string tes = lines[i].Substring(te, 64); int[] ArrayName = ReturnArray(tes);`

Comment: I've kinda figured out what's wrong but haven't completely fixed the problem.. But since you where so helpful I'm just going to accept your answer